# Why in ArcMap, batch processing with custom model, gives each output identical name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, batch

In ArcMap 10.7, I'm trying to use batch processing on a custom model. The problem I'm having as seen from the picture below, is that the output files are given the name of the first output file, even though I explicitly name them based on their input file, each of which is unique.  You can see in the picture that even though the output file names are different on process 1,2, and 3; when I actually open the tool it assigns the output name of each file as the first name on the list.

In the picture below, I've opened process #3 on the list.  In the list the output name is correct, but when I open that item its names after the first process.  It's the same no matter how many process iterations I add.

When I run the tool it appears that the first process writes a file with the output name, then each subsequent process writes over that file.

[image]

There's also a picture of my model:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I find the batch processing approach you are using is flaky for all but the simplest scenario. I would personally abandon this approach. If it truly is just three iterations why not drop the model 3 times into a master model and complete it like that?

Comment: As a workaround could you use an iterator and the %Name% variable?

Comment: ModelBuilder is notoriously clunky but I believe @johns has the right approach with his comment.

Comment: It's for a process meant to run many more than 3 times. This setup was just to demo this behavior.

Comment: Anyways I only resorted to batch processing because I can't get this to work with the iterator.  I'l probably just post that next.